# Подмена фрагментов

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Есть активность в которой есть вот такой код который вызывается при выборе клиента в DrawerLayout фрагмента:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);

if (fragment == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "fragment is null. Add fragment");
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, fragmentTarget).commit();
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "fragment is not null. Replace fragment");

        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentTarget).addToBackStack(null)
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).commit();
    }
```

По моей логике если переменная fragment не указан я считаю что программа запустилась первый раз и добавляю фрагмент. Если же указан значит пользователь сделал какое то телодвижение уже и нужно фрагмент заменить. При этом я хочу что бы при нажатии кнопки назад у меня загружался предыдущий фрагмент. В текущей реализации при старте программы первый фрагмент добавляется, затем после телодвижения пользователя второй фрагмент подменяется. На практике я получаю ошибку:

> E/InputEventSender: Exception dispatching finished signal.
>
> E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback

Наверное важное уточнение, в первом фрагменте у меня используется RecyclerView и в трассировке ошибке есть ссылка на код:

```
            mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Откровенно говоря я не совсем улавливаю здесь связь, почему он ругается на это место. Если нужны какие то еще данные то пишите я все предаставлю.

Comment: а почему вы на null проверяете `fragment`, а добавляете `fragmentTarget` , причем в обоих ветках условия один и тот же? Алгоритм совсем не ясен, какой смысл заменять фрагмент на самого же себя.

Comment: @pavlofff Чего то вчера я ввел вас в заблужение Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);